# Crear QUERY con tres datos de una misma tabla

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ms-access

Me gustaría realizar una QUERY SQL a través de Access, que me permita ver en una columna el nombre del trabajador y en la otra el nombre de su supervisor correspondiente.
[image: Tabla Trabajador]

He intentado con la siguiente QUERY, pero al hacer la consulta solamente me muestra el nombre de un trabajador y el nombre de su supervisor (en este caso son la misma persona).

```
SELECT
    TRABAJADOR.NOMBRE, TRABAJADOR.NOMBRE AS SUPERVISOR
FROM
    TRABAJADOR
WHERE 
     TRABAJADOR.ID_TRABAJADOR = TRABAJADOR.ID_SUPV
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para lograr eso debes usar la **cláusula inner join**, esta cláusula te permite relacionar dos tablas por un campo en común:

```
select t.nombre, s.nombre
from Trabajador t inner join Supervisor s
on t.idSupervisor = s.idSupervisor
```

Como ves aquí se usa la **cláusula inner join** para relacionar las **tablas Trabajador y Supervisor** por el **campo idSupervisor** que deben tener ambas tablas y seleccionar el nombre del Trabajador y su Supervisor.

**Nota**: En la consulta que te pongo doy nombres hipotéticos a los campos, quizá tus nombres sean otros, revisa bien.